# How to know what priority to use with add_action()?

Tags: actions

I was writing a small plugin to remove some menu items for non-admin users from the backend, and discovered that my plugin didn't do anything unless I specified a priority in my code:

```
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'remove_toolbar_items', 999);
```

Without the `999`, the code doesn't remove the items in my `remove_toolbar_items` function, and with it it works great:

```
function remove_toolbar_items( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('new-post');
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('comments');
    }
}
```

The [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) for the priority parameter state:

> Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a
>   particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier
>   execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the
>   order in which they were added to the action. Default value: 10

However I didn't find anything that explains how you're supposed to determine what priority to use. How do you determine when to use priority, and what priority to use? I feel like I could've been scratching my head for hours if I hadn't toyed around with the priority parameter.

Also, I see that the default priority is 10, but is there a known range of priority values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> range of priority values?
>   range of priority values?

Generally, speaking, you can't know *a priori* what priority something is hooked with. The priority needed depends on how other callbacks where hooked in. Often that is the default value of 10 but it could be anywhere between `PHP_INT_MIN` (negative integers are still integers) and `PHP_INT_MAX` and there is no way to be sure except by experiment and, if possible (as with the Core and any themes or plugins that you are specifically concerned with), by examining the source.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like the core should have some little built-in utility to give you this information.

Comment: That's not correct information and can't be answer. Mohammed Asif answered correctly. has_filter('init', 'some_hook') allows to know what priority action has.

Answer (score 8):

WordPress puts your actions into an array with an indexed priorities. You can see this by printing out ( in the admin panel `admin_init` ) `$wp_filter`:

****Note**** as @s_ha_dum points out in the comments below, `admin_init` may not catch *all* added hooks into the action, the more reliable print out may be hooking into [`shutdown`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/shutdown) instead.

```
function filter_print() {
    global $wp_filter;
    print_r( $wp_filter['admin_bar_menu'] );
    die();
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'filter_print' );
```

This gives us a neat array that looks something like this: ( simplified )

```
Array(
    [admin_bar_menu] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [wp_admin_bar_my_account_menu] => Array (
                [function] => wp_admin_bar_my_account_menu
                [accepted_args] => 1
            )
            [wp_admin_bar_sidebar_toggle] => Array (
                [function] => wp_admin_bar_sidebar_toggle
                [accepted_args] => 1
            )
        )

        [4] => Array (
            [wp_admin_bar_search_menu] => Array (
                [function] => wp_admin_bar_search_menu
                [accepted_args] => 1
            )
        )

        [7] => Array (
            [wp_admin_bar_my_account_item] => Array (
                [function] => wp_admin_bar_my_account_item
                [accepted_args] => 1
            )
        )

        [10] => Array (
            [wp_admin_bar_wp_menu] => Array (
                [function] => wp_admin_bar_wp_menu
                [accepted_args] => 1
            )
        )

        [20] => ...
    )
)
```

The 0, 4, 7, 10, and so forth are the priorities of the actions, when a new action is added it's defaulted to 10, similar to index 0 in the example above, they are just stacked into the same index of the array. Considering that many hooks are added into this particular action you would want to at the very end or at last after a specific action was run ( such as menus ). 1 of the two priorities could also work just as effectively: `81` or `201`.

For the most part, the default priority of 10 is sufficient enough. Other times you want to add your hook direct after another ( to maybe nullify it's purpose or remove a specific item ) at which case you can use the `global $wp_filter;` to figure out where it needs to go.

Comment: I thought about this, but it is only going to show things hooked in before or on `admin_init`  and only things hooked in on the current install. It says nothing about what an as yet uninstalled plugin or theme might do.  +1 anyway.

Comment: @s_ha_dum That's a good point, I imagine you could also use something like `admin_footer` though right? Or would that be the same issue?

Comment: The [`shutdown`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/shutdown) hook would be your best bet, but only for installed code and even then, things can be conditionally hooked so it may be possible to miss some anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Well, there's a way to find the priority of an action.

we can use the following code`has_action( $tag, $function_to_check )` which Optionally returns the priority on that hook for the specified function.

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_action

Answer (score -1):

Just in case someone is looking for WordPress Action Priority/Reference list, the full hook link is here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/